# How to add elements to a String but not reset it each time?

Tags: java

I am having some trouble with Strings in java. Below is a code that when given 2 numbers `start` and `end` it would return something like `1 + 2 + 3 +`  if start was 1 and end was 4. But my code (below) would only return `3 +` . So how would I make it so that adds a new element to the string each time the for loop is run rather than resetting the whole thing?

```
String sumString = "";

        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {  
            
            sumString = i + " + ";
        }
```

Comment: If using Java 8+, you could simplify the whole lot to `String sumString = IntStream.range(start, end).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(" + "));`

Comment: In your loop, just change to ``sumString = sumString + i + " + ";``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i + " + "`should be added to `sumString` and reassigned to `sumString`.

Replace

```
sumString = i + " + ";
```

with

```
sumString = sumString + i + " + ";
```

A shortcut to write it is as follows:

```
sumString += i + " + ";
```

Answer (score 3):

just simply add + in front of the =

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sumString = "";
        int start = 1;
        int end =4;
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {

            sumString += i + " + ";
        }
        System.out.println(sumString);
    }
}
```